# Prove that the Set of Bounded Linear Operators is Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $B(V,V')$ be the vector space formed by set of linear operators $T:V\rightarrow V'$. where $V,V'$ are normed vector spaces. Equip $B(V,V')$ with the norm 
$$
\|T\|=\sup\frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|} 
$$
where $x\in V$.
Show that if $V'$ is Banach then $(B(V,V'),\|\cdot\|)$ is Banach.

(!!Beware that I am bad with quantifiers!!)

Proof:

1. Find potential limit.
   Let $\{T_n\}_{n\geq1}$  be a Cauchy in $B(V,V')$, then $\forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists N\geq 1 $ s.t. $n,m\geq N\Rightarrow$
   $$
    \sup\|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|<\varepsilon \|x\| ,
   $$
   then
   $$
    \|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|\leq\sup\|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|<\varepsilon \|x\|,
   $$
   and so $\{T_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is Cauchy in $V'$ which is Banach, and so has a limit $T\in V'$.
2. Show that the limit is in the space.
   W.t.s. that $T$ is bounded and linear
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
   \|T(x)\| &\leq \|T_n(x)-T(x)\|+\|T_n(x)\| \\ &=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|+\|T_n(x)\| \\ & \leq \limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty}\|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|+\|T_n(x)\| \\ & \leq \varepsilon \|x\|+\|T_n(x)\|
   \end{split}
   \end{equation}
   Linearity.
   $$
   T_n(\lambda x+\mu y)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}T_n(\lambda x+\mu y)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\lambda T_n(x)+\mu T_n(y))=\lambda T(x)+\mu T(y)
   $$
3. Show that the Cauchy sequence converges in norm.
   W.t.s. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup\|T_n(x)-T(x)\|=0$.
   For all $n,m\geq N$
   $$
    \|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|\leq\sup\|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|<\varepsilon \|x\|.
   $$
   Take the limit in $m\rightarrow\infty$
   $$
    \|T_n(x)-T(x)\|<\varepsilon \|x\|.
   $$
   Take the supremum
   $$
    \sup\|T_n(x)-T(x)\|<\varepsilon \|x\|.
   $$
   but $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary and $\|x\|$ finite.

Comment: What is your question? You have proved the easy part. (it seems to be correct.). The converse is true also: if $B(V,V')$ with operator norm is Banach, then $V'$ is Banach. This is the hardest part. (Hint: you need the Hahn-Banach theorem.)

Comment: I just wanted to see if I structured the proof properly using the quantifiers in the correct way besides the eventual "corerctness" of the proof. Thanks I'll look into the opposite implication.

Comment: Quantifiers look good ;) there is some technical issue. For example, in $\sup\|T_n(x)-T_m(x)\|<\varepsilon \|x\|$ you don't have to take the $\sup$, since you're working with $x$ fixed in that context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof of (1) is incorrect. You start with a Cauchy sequence $\{T_n\} \subset B(V,V')$, and prove that it has a limit in $V$?!

What you want to do (and I suspect this is what you are trying to do) is as follows :

(1) For each $x\in V$, you check that $\{T_n(x)\} \subset V'$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $V'$ is a Banach space, this sequence as a limit, which you can denote by $\alpha_x$.

(2) Now check that the elements $\{\alpha_x : x\in V\}$ satisfy the properties of a linear transformation. ie for any $x,y \in V$ and $c\in \mathbb{K}$,
$$
\alpha_{x+y} = \alpha_x + \alpha_y
$$
$$
\alpha_{cx} = c\alpha_x
$$

(3) So define $T : V \to V'$ by $T(x) = \alpha_x$, and check that $T$ defines a bounded linear map.

Now conclude that $T_n \to T$ in the operator norm defined on $B(V,V')$.

Comment: Assume you know that `V'` is Banach. I think the same situation applies to show that `B(V,V')` is Banach as here. Right?

Comment: What happens in proof of 1, if ||x|| is not finite?